# Precise search inside a pdf

Tags: search, pdf

I wanted to search inside a PDF with Adobe Acrobat Reader for MacOS (or the one built in with MacOS). I want to search, for example, for the *capital* letter "U".

Is it possible and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

A tutorial online [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Search-for-a-Word-or-Phrase-in-a-PDF-Document) for Adobe Acrobat Reader indicates in step 4 how to do a *case-sensitive* search, which is what you're looking for.

Press `Ctrl-F` to start a search in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Enter the letter `U` and then tick (select) the check-box next to "Case-Sensitive" search. Press the `Search` button to start the search.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.